# Caliper position effect on braking or suspension?

Tags: suspension, braking

According to http://www.bicycling.com/mountainbikecom/featured-stories/jacks-not-here-man

> Where the caliper grips the rotor along its diameter makes no difference in braking or suspension behavior.

Does "no" really mean "zero", as the article claims? (I often find that universal claims are overstated, so I look out for them.)

Or is the article exaggerating the point that the "most important" forces with regards to suspension comes from the contact patch effect?

Answer (score 2):

So long as the caliper attachment point is rigidly connected to the axle, precisely where along the circumference of the rotor (or wheel, for rim brakes) the caliper sits is of no consequence (other than to the designer, who must consider stresses on the "rigid" components).  Braking force and forces applied to suspension components do not change based on the location of the caliper.

Note that position will, to a significant degree, affect such factors as the torque put on the "tine" of the front fork, which may in turn result in such things as a slight twist in the caliper position while braking, but these effects can only occur to the extent that the "rigid" components aren't, quite.

Answer (score 1):

The article is correct, as far as the suspension goes.

Technically the brake force being applied to a different part of the rotor would mean you've moved the brake caliper, which could influence the way that force is felt on the seat/chainstay (depending on where the mounts are). However, if you're moving the caliper significantly, then you've probably already thought of bolstering the mounting point.